# PL/SQL to fetch sample rows for each month in a year

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to fetch 200 rows a month per year randomly sampled for each month from this table in Oracle 10g:

```
Documents
--------------------------------------
Doc_ID     Date
95687      25-AUG-12
99283      21-SEP-12
87654      10-AUG-12
97111      14-SEP-12
```

I've seen the `SAMPLE()` function but not sure how to do the other parts of the criteria.

Comment: Thanks, APC. Please see the updated question again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
select doc_id
       , date
from (  select doc_id
               , date
               , row_number() over (partition by trunc(date, 'MM')
                                    order by dbms_randon.value ) as rn
         from your_table )
 where rn <= 200
 order by date, doc_id ;
```

The analytic ROW_NUMBER() function produces a number for each record grouped by month (achieved by truncating the date with the `'MM'` mask).  Ordering by DBMS_RANDOM will randomise the sort order.  Remember to initialise DBMS_RANDOM before running the query to get a truly random sort order.
[Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_random.htm#i996798)